# Problem generating public and private keys with password via openssl without shell interaction

Tags: bash, openssl

Problem:

Generate pair private & public keys with input onetime

My attempt (files are not created):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please input secret: " secret

mkdir -p ./src/app-for-purchasing-service/config/jwt

openssl genrsa -passout pass:"$secret" -aes256 -out ./src/app-for-purchasing-service/config/jwt/new-private.pem 4096
openssl rsa -pubout -in ./src/app-for-purchasing-service/config/jwt/new-private.pem -passin pass:$secret ./src/app-for-purchasing-service/config/jwt/new-public.pem -passout pass:$secret
echo $secret >> ./src/app-for-purchasing-service/.env
```

Comment: So, what happens when you run this script? Are you getting an error message? Unexpected results?

Comment: `Please input secret:
Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
..................................++++
..............................................++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
rsa: Use -help for summary.` @larsks

Comment: Can you edit that output into your question, so that we can see the formatting correctly? It would also be helpful to know which command output what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please input secret: " secret

mkdir -p ./src/app-for-purchasing-service/config/jwt

openssl genrsa -passout pass:"$secret" -aes256 -out ./src/app-for-purchasing-service/config/jwt/private.pem 4096
openssl rsa -pubout -passin pass:$secret -in ./src/app-for-purchasing-service/config/jwt/private.pem -out ./src/app-for-purchasing-service/config/jwt/public.pem
echo "JWT_PASS=$secret" >>./src/app-for-purchasing-service/.env
```